# Lock a record from other users when editing by single user in CakePHP 2.4

Tags: cakephp, locking, cakephp-2.0

I am implementing a CakePHP 2.4 app.

I have `User` and `Article` as Models.

I have no `articles/view` action; only `articles/edit` and `articles/delete actions`.

When any `User` accesses the `articles/edit` webpage regardless as a `GET` or `POST`, that particular `Article` is locked from editing/deleting by other Users.

The following is the crucial part I need advice on.

*If a User stays on `articles/edit/23` but there is no activity for 30 minutes,*

-- OR --

*When the User leaves `articles/edit/23` page,*

then the `articles/23` is now available for edit/delete by other Users.

Off the top of my mind, i know that in articles table, i need a field called currently_locked_by field that holds the user_id of the User currently in control.

**My problem is with detecting the session inactivity and knowing that the User has left the edit page.**

I am defining session inactivity in the edit page as ***when the User does not type anything in any input elements or changes any dropdown selection or checks/uncheck any checkbox***.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a lock table with a combination of the user, resource and lock time.  (Regarding your spec's when to start the inactivity - I recommend going simpler to start: "when they person loads the page".  Otherwise you are also writing javascript to write to your database at the end of every field change.)

Whenever a person goes to the edit page,

1. They check that table for the resource and lock time.  If the record does not exist or the lock time has been exceeded it is safe for them to edit.
2. If they can edit, then they insert a record as needed (and delete any records with that resource.)

This should take care of the timeout requirement as long you make sure the person still has a lock (or another hasn't locked the record) when they try to save their changes.

One technique to handle the leaving of pages, is to put in a beforeFilter test that removes all locks for that person.  The downsides

- You still can't tell if the person leaves and goes to some external
  site.
- The beforeFilter does add overhead to every page view.
- If your users run two or more tabs, then navigating other tabs will
  release the lock.

You could also just have every outbound link on that page release the lock (like going to an interstitial page) and let any departures via closing the tab, using address bar, etc  timeout.  (It depends on how your users work.)